# ¿como puedo vincular una funcion de java script a un html y mostrar el rsultado de la msima?

Tags: javascript, html

hace unos dias me salio una taream era de realizar un programa que tome las funciones de un archivo java script y con un boton muestre el resultado de las mismas en un archivo html...

me podrian ayudar?

button class="btn" src="codigo.js">Comentarios< use esto pero no me da el resultado que quiero

Answer (score 1):

Te pondre un ejemplo, pero debiste buscar informacion ya que esto es muy basico

```
 <button onclick="mensaje()">Ejecuta funcion</button>
   <script src="archivo.js"></script>
```

agrega algo como esto dentro del `<body>`, la etiqueta `<button>` tiene la propiedad `onclick` esta ejecuta la funcion llamada **mensaje**.

La funcion llamada mensaje se declara en un archivo externo llamado **archivo.js**, en este archivo escribe todas tus funciones.

En el archivo externo agrega algo como:

```
function mensaje(){
    alert("Ejecutaste la funcion");
}
```

y ese archivo lo llamas desde el **html** con la etiqueta `<script>` y su atributo `src`.